# Segmentation fault (core dumped), working with dynamic vectors

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

package.c:

```
double * foo(int length) {

int i;
double * a;

a = malloc(sizeof(double) * length)

for(i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
     a[i] = 0.0;
}

return a;
}
```

main.c

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    double * vector;

    vector = foo(999999);

    for(i =0;i < 999999; i++) {
         printf("%f", vector[i]);
    }

    return 0
}
```

What's the problem with my code? I'm getting segmentation fault(core dumped), my dinamic vectors are always with more than 1m elements.

Comment: It's dynamic, I believe. :)

Comment: you never defined `x`... so you have no way of knowing how long that loop will run for.

Comment: are you mixing `length` and `x`?

Comment: @MarcB `x` is usualy the unknown one :)

Comment: fixed, x was the length

Comment: You are aware of that [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) can fail? And that it will return a null pointer then? What do you think will happen when you access a null pointer?  Please read about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @SouravGhosh Actually I don't see anything dynamic here... Fixed pretty much...

Comment: is the fault inside `foo` or in the print loop.  Are you sure `malloc` didn't return `NULL`?  (something you should check for before initializing the array)

Comment: You main file should have declaration of `foo()`. If `foo` is written in some header file, include that particular header.

Comment: You should also free the memory before exit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The title is not yet _fixed_ :)

Comment: Ahh.. let me do that..

Comment: Shavan40 has a good point, without a declaration, C is going to assume `int foo(int)` , although you'd think at the assignment to `vector` the compiler would have warned on that.

Comment: @infixed And I am pretty sure it have warned..

Answer (score 0):

Your main file doesn't contain a declaration for `foo`.  So the compiler assumes the declaration is `int foo()`, i.e. a function that takes an unknown number of arguments and returns an `int`.

When compiling you should have gotten a warning similar to this:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘foo’
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

As a result, the return value isn't being captured correctly resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifested in a core dump.

Add a prototype to main and that should fix the error.

```
double * foo(int length);

int main(void) {
   ...
```

You should also `#include <stdio.h>` in main.c and `#include <stdlib.h>` in package.c and main.c to get the prototypes of `printf` and `malloc` respectively.

Also, don't forget to `free(vector)` at the end of your program to clean up the allocated memory.

Comment: That reminds me, are we going to see a `#include "package.c"` sooner?

Comment: I alreaady imported the required libraries and the prototypes, my question is:

Comment: I created a dinamic vector in package.c, why can't I acess any element in main.c?

Comment: @user5693 We can't believe you, unless you show us the full code (AKA MCVE)

Comment: @user5693 I tested your code with and without the declaration in this answer.  Without it, the program core dumped.  With it, it ran successfully.  So add `double * foo(int length);` to the top of main and it will work.